# Adding default external network in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to learn docker and understanding docker-compose

As I was trying out the external network section:

```
 networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

I understand that 
'my-pre-existing-network' needs to be created.

Is it possible to create a new default external network from within the compose file itself?

This is more from a learning/understanding perspective And also alternative to the docker network create command. Thanks.

Comment: no you need to use the command docker network to create it first

Comment: The network `my-pre-existing-network` needs to be exist (`docker-compose` won't create networks specified as external) - it could be a `docker network` that was created from a different composition or a network created using the [`docker network create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) command.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, check your version of the file. For version 3.6, the following examples can meet your needs:

**Example 1:**

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  webserver:
...
#add existing database network 
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy_host
```

**Example 2:**

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  webserver:
...
#add existing database network 
networks:
  default:
    name: proxy_host
    external: true
```

**Example 3:** This configuration creates new networks.

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  webserver:
    networks:
      - proxy_host
      - database_host
...
networks:
  proxy_host: {}
  database_host: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you create a network within your compose-file then that one is not considered to be "external". You can create a custom network using network section:

```
version: '3'

services:
    my-service:
    # can be a pre-built image like this or built locally (check reference)
        image: some-image:latest 
        networks:
            - custom-network

networks:
    custom-network:
        driver: bridge
```

If you are going to use your compose file with swarm, you might want to choose `driver: overlay`. Additional information can be found [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/understanding-docker-networking-drivers-use-cases/).

Comment: Note that Docker Compose will create and use a network named `default` for you, automatically, with exactly this configuration, so you can delete all of the `networks:` blocks in this setup to the same effect.  I'm not clear it's what the questioner was asking for, though.

Answer (score 2):

Ref. the ["use a pre-existing network"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) documentation: "Instead of attempting to create a network called `[projectname]_default`, Compose looks for a network called `my-pre-existing-network` and connect your app’s containers to it." - `docker-compose` will not attempt to create the network.

The `external` network must already exist (e.g. "`my-pre-existing-network`"), it could be a `docker network` created from a different `docker-compose` environment or a `docker network` created using the [`docker network create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) command.

**Note**: `docker-compose` networks are prefixed with [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name). You can use [`docker network ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_ls/) to list existing networks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone still looking for answer. Probably this will work.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    networks:
      - test

networks:
   test:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```